# Power Arduino Over 9V automatically after being disconnected from USB 5V

Tags: arduino-uno

Am wondering if there is some way the Arduino can automatically power itself using through the 9v port in case the USB is disconnected, and afterwards if the USB is connected again it stop feeding from the 9v Input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser is somewhat.

If you connect a 9V battery to Vin, I'll "take over" the power wheter if the USB is connected or not. Note tought that some problems may occur when both are connected at the same time (personnal opinion). See this [link](http://www.open-electronics.org/the-power-of-arduino-this-unknown/) for more info.

**So in conclusion, if you have a USB, remove the 9V for power efficiency. Once you include the 9V though, it will take over control of the power on the ARDUINO.**

Comment: Actually the opposite is the case. The USB takes over if the 9V is removed. If 9V is there it is used for power regardless of whether USB is there or not.

Comment: @Majenko, good point! I've modified the anwser!

Comment: I need the Arduino to power itself when the USB is removed, but not use the 9V if its connected. And this need to be done automatically and not manually.

Comment: @Majenko IF I connect Both USB and Power Jack, it's going to choose the power from the power jack over 5Volts. Yet will the serial be available?

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin Yes and yes.

Comment: @Majenko Powering both USB and 9V Jack won't burn the Arduino. You 100% Sure?

Comment: Positive. The Arduino is designed specifically to work like that.

Comment: Bro my life gonna be easier ^^ It's gonna open a new world to my Home-Automation project :D Like some post wrote it can burn your Arduino :| But it doesn't according to you :D

Comment: If you do home automation, connect use a 5V wallplug. Its more efficient then a 9V battery

Comment: @Majenko The Jack input not working, am using the adapter which came with the arduino and its not working at all. :| Its not turning on, nothing connected to it, its powering over USB and I upload a Led Blink sketch this works fine on USB but on the jack alone its not working.

Answer (score 3):

there is one way you can make it.
you can use a temporary capacitor(with a voltage output near to 9v)(or a lipo battery) connected to arduino's voltage input pin and 9v battery connected to arduino with a transistor.
whatever program you are uploading to arduino, you can add a code that reads the serial port, and if serial port is not available then it opens the transistor's gate so as the capacitor gets discharged very quickly the 9v battery takes the job.when it gets the serial port again it closes the transistor's gate and arduino stops feeding upon battery and takes power from USB port.

Comment: A lipo connected to Vin is impossible. Vin is connected to the input of the V regulator which needs a voltage more then 7V to operate proprelly.